# QPushButton() should react as long as it is pressed

Tags: qt, button, mouse, pressed, click

I am using QPushButton() in my programme. With these buttons I rotate my object.
Works fine so far. The only Problem is that i have to click multiple times to rotate the object a little further. This is a bit annoying. Isnt there a possibility that the button will stay pressed as long as I press it and the object will rotate further. There is the function pressed(), but there is no difference to clicked().

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[QAbstractButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) has an auto-repeat feature that you can turn on:

```
button->setAutoRepeat(true);
```

This will emit the pressed(), released(), and clicked() signals repeatedly.  You can also specify how often the signals are emitted (`setAutoRepeatInterval`), and how long the button waits before it starts emitting them (`setAutoRepeatDelay`).